# Why does Rust have struct and enum?

Tags: rust

Rust's enums are algebraic datatypes. As far as I can tell this seems to subsume what struct is. What is different about struct that necessitates keeping it?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, if such a thing exists (I don't think it does), it is *very* hard to find. Of all the [questions for "struct enum"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=struct+enum+%5Brust%5D+is%3Aquestion), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231320/how-do-enum-vs-struct-type-names-work-in-rust) is the closest, but it's not the same question at all.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First of all, you are correct that semantically `enum` is strictly superior to the `struct` as to what it can represent, and therefore `struct` is somewhat redundant.

However, there are other elements at play here.

- ease of use: the values within an `enum` can only be accessed (directly) through matching; contrast with the ease of use of accessing a `struct` field. You could write accessors for each and every field, but that is really cumbersome.
- distinction: an `enum` is a tagged union, a `struct` has a fixed-layout; we (programmers) generally like to put labels on things, and therefore giving different names to different functionality can be appreciated.

As I see it, `struct` is therefore syntactic sugar. I usually prefer lean and mean, but a bit of sugar can go a long way in increasing what can be represented tersely.

Comment: Note: There are (experimental) "struct variants", so the documentation point might become obsolete in the future.

Comment: Is `enum` strictly superior to `struct`? It seems like `enum` is dependent on `struct`s and `tuple`s for storing more than one element per variant. I suppose removing `struct`s but keeping `tuple`s would allow `enum`s to fulfill all roles that `struct`s can.

Comment: @8bittree: You can store multiple fields in a single variant, or in a tuple, ... but you cannot *name* them.

Comment: I'm under the impression that storing multiple fields in a single variant is done through the use of a tuple, or struct, rather than some other mechanism. Although I think in the case of a tuple, they sugar away one pair of parenthesis.

Comment: Hmm... after a bit more thought, and looking at the Rust book, I think it depends on the definition of `enum`. With the narrow, bare-essential definition of "It's one of these variants, each variant contains a single piece of payload data" it's orthogonal to structs. With the broader definition as containing the entirety of the behavior actually in Rust, then yes enums make structs technically redundant (also tuples). I'm somewhat uncomfortable with that, because using the narrow definition, the current behavior of enums can be perfectly replicated through the use of struct and tuple payloads.

Comment: @MatthieuM. struct-like variants in enums `Foo { bar: i32 }` are stable for quite a while now already. Maybe you want to update your answer :)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: Good point. Now it's tagged union vs access without matching.

Comment: enum isn't *strictly* superior to struct, they are different.  Lukas Kalbertodt touches on this by explaining that enum "cannot construct product types" -- if data type has multiple independent components which need to be accessed separately, an enum would be cumbersome

Comment: An enum has a discriminant, and a struct doesn't. That's a significant difference.

Comment: @ClementCherlin: Whilst the (default) layout of `enum`s is unstable, [a single-variant `enum` does not have any discriminant on current stable](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5d3633bd946635aa55a28321c995b69f).

Comment: Another fact that might be interest to note is that if we do something like `pub enum Months {
    April,
    May
}`, all of the fields are set to public. Whereas in a `struct`, each field needs to explicitly be set to`pub`, even if the `struct` is marked as `pub`.

Answer (score 28):

Firstly, Rust has a wide array of data types:

- Structs with named fields (`struct Foo {bar: uint}`)
- Tuple structs (`struct Foo(pub Bar, Baz)`)
- Structs with no fields (`struct Foo;`)
- Enums, with various types of variants:

  - Variants with no fields (eg `None`)
  - Tuple variants (eg `Some(T)`)
  - Struct variants (eg `Some { pub inner :T }`)

This gives the programmer some flexibility in defining datatypes. Often, you don't want named fields, especially if the struct/variant has only one field. Rust lets you use tuple structs/tuple variants in that case.

If structs were removed from Rust there would be no  loss of functionality, enums with struct variants could be used again. But there would be an overwhelming number of single-variant enums which would be unnecessary and cumbersome to use.

Answer (score 18):

Not 100% correct, but another nice way to think about it : `enum` isn't actually superior to `struct`, the syntax sugar just makes it look like it is.

An `enum` is a sum type meaning that it's value is one value of one of a set of other types. The [`Result<T, E>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) type is *either* of type `T` or `E`. So each `enum` variant has exactly **one** type associated with it. Everything else (no type, tuple variants and struct variants) *could* be syntax sugar.

```
enum Animal {
    // without syntax sugar
    Cat(i32),  
    // desugars to `Dog(())` (empty tuple/unit) 
    Dog,
    // desugars to `Horse((i32, bool))` (tuple)
    Horse(i32, bool),
    // desugars to `Eagle(GeneratedEagleType)` and a struct definition outside
    // of this enum `struct GeneratedEagleType { weight: i32, male: bool }`
    Eagle { weight: i32, male: bool }
}
```

So it would be enough if each `enum` variant would be associated with exactly one type. And in that case `enum` is not superior to `struct`, because it cannot construct product types (like `struct`).

To be able write the "type definition" inside the enum variant definition is just for convenience.

Also: `struct` is superior to "tuple structs" and "tuples", too. If we ignore the names those three things are [nearly](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/unsized-types.html) equivalent. But Rust still has those three different kinds of types for convenience.

---

Please note that I don't know if those enum definitions are actually syntax sugar or not. But they *could* be and that might help think about. it

Answer (score 3):

## Visibility

Not to find reason in what may be a transient implementation detail (I'm not on the core team and have no insight), but

- A public enum can not hold or contain a private struct.
- A public struct can hold or contain a private enum.

### See also

- [Why does "can't leak private type" only apply to structs and not enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680064/why-does-cant-leak-private-type-only-apply-to-structs-and-not-enums)

Answer (score 2):

Another important distinction along with the above answers is that enum at one point can **ONLY** be one of the values stated while struct represents values for all the parameters for that instance.
eg.

```
enum Things{
Box, 
Page(i32),
}

struct Things{
box: Option<String>,
page: i32,
}
```

In the above case a single **enum** can **either** be a Box or a Page, while a single instance of **struct** will represent a box **and** a page.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that enums and traits and their inheritance by structs both implement algebraic datatypes.

However traits is an extensible set of types, where any stuct can be attributed any trait from any piece of code. Using introspection, it is possible to expect a value with a given trait, and dynamically dig out the actual type of a struct. But that type is among a set of types that is unpredictable, because any struct could be given the said trait from anywhere.

Whereas enums define once and for all a limited type hierarchy, making it predictable and straightforward to go match subtypes as if they were simple values. The language features surrounding enums can therefore be optimized so that the type checks occur statically, providing much greater performance, and some sugar in the language. But also the hierarchy description is contained to the enum definition, and does not impact the trait type system.

TL;DR: enum narrows down a hierarchy of types in a contained manner, instead of relying on traits that are extensible by any piece of code and impacts everything.