# Why does "can't leak private type" only apply to structs and not enums?

Tags: struct, enums, rust, private-members

In [*Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/first-layout.html), they show that a `pub enum` can't hold a private `struct`:,

```
struct Node {
    elem: i32,
    next: List,
}

pub enum List {
    Empty,
    More(Box<Node>),
}
```

This will cause the compiler to complain:

```
error[E0446]: private type `Node` in public interface
 --> src/main.rs:8:10
  |
8 |     More(Box<Node>),
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^ can't leak private type
```

But this code will not cause an error even though `Link` is private:

```
pub struct List {
    head: Link,
}

enum Link {
    Empty,
    More(Box<Node>),
}

struct Node {
    elem: i32,
    next: Link,
}
```

What is the reason for this discrepancy? Why does a private enum not cause an error while a private struct does?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the first example, the enum `List` is public.  That means that the enum variant `More` is also public.  However, `More` cannot be used by external code because `Node` *isn't* public.  Thus, you have a thing that is externally visible, but can't actually be *used*, which is probably not what you wanted.

In the second example, the struct `List` is public.  However, the `head` field is *not* public.  Thus, it doesn't matter whether `Link` is public or not, because external code can't see the `head` field in the first place.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that in rust public code *cannot* access external private code, but private code *can* access external private code?