# Rust's Enums vs Generics

Tags: generics, enums, rust

There seem to be two similar ways to structure data in Rust:

```
pub enum FooEnum {
    Bar {ts: DateTime, bar: Bar},
    Baz {ts: DateTime, baz: Baz}
}
```

and

```
pub struct FooGeneric<T: BarAndBazLike> {
    pub ts: DateTime<Utc>,
    pub content: T
}
```

I can see that the enum approach gives me the nicer fieldnames `foo` and `bar`, at the cost of the repeated definition of `ts`.

Are there advantages to using the generic approach?  (I will be using serde with JSON and bincode.)

Comment: All variants of the enum will have the same size, while the generic structures will (may) not. I.e. you will not abe able to assign instances of the structure with  different generic parameter to the same variable, while you will be able to assign different enum variants to the same enum variable. And no - enums are not run-time polymorphic - read about `traits` and dynamic dispatch if you need runtime polymorphism

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Rust have struct and enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26437043/why-does-rust-have-struct-and-enum)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics usually have better performance since the compiler can generate specialized code for each variant. They also take up slightly less memory, since enums need to store a discriminant to keep track of which variant is currently in use.

OTOH, enums don't need to know the type at compile-time and can even change content-types on the fly during execution.

Another option if you don't want to repeat the `ts` field is to use [`either`](https://crates.io/crates/either):

```
extern crate either; // 1.5.3
extern crate chrono; // 0.4.13

use either::Either;
use chrono::{ DateTime, Utc };

pub struct Bar {}
pub struct Baz {}

pub struct Foo {
    pub ts: DateTime<Utc>,
    pub content: Either<Bar, Baz>,
}
```

Or to use a custom enum for just the `content` field:

```
extern crate chrono; // 0.4.13

use chrono::{ DateTime, Utc };

pub struct Bar {}
pub struct Baz {}

pub enum BarOrBaz {
    Bar (Bar),
    Baz (Baz),
}

pub struct Foo {
    pub ts: DateTime<Utc>,
    pub content: BarOrBaz,
}
```